# Error al mandar formulario por POST en php

Tags: php

tengo un formulario que lo quiero mandar por post, en el tengo varios inputs ocultos con variables...

```
<input type="hidden" name="idUsuario" value="<?php echo $IdUsuario ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="telefono" value="<?php echo $telefono ?>">
```

pero al momento de enviarlo a la otra pagina me marca errores sobre index

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo solucionar el problema? necesito esas variables para poder introducir datos en la base de datos

asi es como lo intento recibir

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$correo = $_POST['email'];
$IdUsuario =$_POST['idUsuario'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
```

> Form

```
<div class="form">
      <form action="" method="POST" id="card-form">
        <span class="card-errors"></span>
        <div>
          <label>
            <span>Nombre</span><br>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            <span>Número</span><br>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            <span>Fecha(MM/AAAA)</span><br>
          <span>/</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
          </label>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="idUsuario" value="<?php echo $IdUsuario ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="telefono" value="<?php echo $telefono ?>">
        <button type="submit">Crear Token</button>
      </form>
```

> Envio de datos a la siguiente pagina

```
var SuccessResponseHandler = function(token) {
    var $form = $("#card-form");
    //Inserta el token_id en la forma para que se envíe al servidor
    $form.append($('<input name="id_token" id="TokenId" type="hidden">').val(token.id));
    //$form.get(0).submit(); //Hace submit
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("card-form"));
    //Llamamos a la función AJAX de jQuery
    $.ajax({
      url: "customer.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    }).done(function(echo){
       alert("Pago exitoso");
    });
};
```

Comment: Añada el `HTML` completo , incluido el `form`.

Comment: @Dev.Joel ya lo coloque

Comment: `formData` no aparece en su código , Su Js está incompleto , ¿Dónde 
 y cuando ejecuta el `Ajax`?

Comment: @Dev.Joel mi error, ya coloque bien el js

Comment: Tiene la función en `SuccessResponseHandler` pero no la llama en ningún lado. Al parecer sigue incompleto su `Js`. y Además está muy confuso lo que intenta resolver. Sí envía por `Ajax` el form es casi imposible que salgan los errores de la imagen. ya que no debería recargar la página ni redirigirse a `customer.php` donde tiene los `index` del error.

Comment: cuando le das clic en el submit no esta pasando atravez de la funcion js porque en ningun momento de tu script detienes el submit y al parecer se esta mandado a la misma pagina donde esta tu formulario

Comment: 1. ¿Cómo se llama el archivo donde está el formulario? 2.¿Está en el mismo directorio que el archivo `customer.php`? 3. ¿Desde dónde llamas la función `SuccessResponseHandler`, para que los datos del formulario se envíen a `customer.php`? El punto 3 lo puedes solucionar dando un `id` al botón del formulario y escuchando los `click` de dicho botón en el código jQuery. 4. ¿Para qué es el token que aparece en tu código y cómo lo usas o validas en `customer.php`?